# PUT requests on RubyOnRails via Passenger 4.0.37 always take 30 seconds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, http, passenger, openproject

We installed a RoR app using libapache2-mod-passenger. This application is 'openproject' (https://www.openproject.org/)

It has been working great for the past few months, but a few days ago, we moved several other stuff to this webserver (that already had php and php module for apache), such as a wordpress instalation and a few custom php pages...

I think I might have done a system upgrade via apt (using Debian 7) but can't recall anything relevant being updated...

The RoR app seemed fine at the time. Now I came to discover that when sumitting something new to this RoR app, it will always take 30 seconds extra!

On the browser shows as a POST, as does on apache log.
The app log shows these requests as PUT, as other POSTS seem to go quick

Funny thing, is also that apache log will only show stuff, past those 30 seconds.

The request made from the browser takes about 31 seconds (varying, but always more than 30) until it gets a 302 code.

Some posts that the RoR app take as post go quick just fine..

I don't know what I should look at, any ideias to fix this 30 second issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a discussion in the OpenProject forums related to this question: https://www.openproject.org/topics/382?r=389

Comment: Hi,

Thank you for linking it here. I started it, but the main goal there, seems to be moving to openproject 3.0, while that may happen, the issue is still present.

Current installation takes 30 seconds when a PUT request comes in !